# sending result to called object (class) from static library class

Tags: ios, static-libraries, nsthread

I have ios project in which I am having static library for initiating webservice request and parsing the response of it.
Now the problem is when I call the method of static library from ios main project class, I want the calling class to wait until the called class performs it's all actions. I tried by using thread but no luck. Anyone can help me?

Thanks,
PMB

Comment: I referred to this thread http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/39402-waiting-response-web-service-call.html
and it helped me a lot sorry for posting the question before goggling more.

Answer (score 0):

Your question needs some more detail Pooja, as a lot of the answer depends on how you've implemented things.

If you have control over the "static library" (meaning you can make code changes to it), I recommend implementing a callback function (or maybe even a delegate method... not 100% certain that this is possible with a static library, but anyways). Then when it's time for the library to call back the UI on the main thread, all that needs to be done is call that callback function or method.

If you don't have control over the "static library", I'd recommend spitting off the calls to the static library in a separate thread (which it sounds like you've already done) and set a timer method in that separate thread to fire every second or whatever to see if the static library has "performed all it's actions" (as you said).

How does that approach sound so far?